# Indexing user query

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I'm trying to add user search queries to an elasticsearch index for autocomplete.

I'm using the JS API for ES like this in my searchService:

```
 this.indexQuery = function (searchTerms) {
   var userQueries = es_return.hits.hits;
    esClient.index({
      index: 'query-index1',
      type: 'autocomplete',
      body: {
        fields: ['suggestions']
      }
    }).then(function(es_return) {
      userQueries.push(searchTerms);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };//eof indexQuery
```

This should add the user typed queries to the 'index' on submission for search, right?

On my `<form>` and `<button>` elements, I have `ng-submit="vm.search(); vm.indexQuery()"`

and indexQuery in my controller looks like this:

```
vm.indexQuery = function(searchTerms) { 
    $http.post('localhost:9200/query-index1/autocomplete', {
      params: {
        suggestions: vm.searchTerms
      }
    }).then (function(response){
      console.log("success");
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("error");
    });
  };
};
```

However, it's just not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: it doesn't look like you are passing anything for the `searchTerms` param of `vm.indexQuery` with the call: `ng-keydown="indexQuery($event)"` - you would need to add a second parameter of whatever your `ng-model`ed inputs are

Comment: you can refer this link https://github.com/vhvinod/AngularJS-ElasticSearch

Comment: @plong0, ok will try that out, thanks

Comment: @plong0, please see UPDATE above

Comment: I've edited the question, after some testing...

Comment: you might try: `$http.post('yoururl', { data: { suggestions: vm.searchTerms }})`  (notice **data** instead of **params**)  please see [angular $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) ... if that is not the problem, you will need to expand more on what exactly is not working - is `vm.indexQuery` getting called?  does `vm.searchTerms` have a value in there?  does the `$http.post` fire correctly?

Comment: @plong0 thanks for the link, reading up on this now

Comment: @plong0 I've been reading up and hopefully gaining in understanding. I think I've been going about this the wrong way. I don't need $http.post, becausing I'm sending an index request to ES - just need to figure out how to call a function to do that when I'm already using ng-submit="search()" ??

Comment: @plong0 I'm happy to report after some more learning, I got it working! It was actually pretty simple... once understanding came.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually incredibly easy, once I got better understanding. All I had to do was call another function at the end of search(), that function called a function in searchService to index the user's query. I also had to add 2 params to my `esClient.index()` function, `opType: "index"` and `refresh: true`. After that it was cake :)!

```
this.indexQuery = function (searchTerms) {
esClient.index({
  index: 'query-index1',
  type: 'autocomplete',
  opType: 'index',
  refresh: true,
  body: {
    fields: ['suggestions']
  }
}).then(function(es_return) {
  console.log('success');
}, function(error) {
  console.log('error');
});
```

};

HTH helps anyone else.